# Reading a post request with image file, and convert in base64 encoding string

Tags: image, forms, file-upload, playframework, playframework-2.0

I wanted to ask how can we read a post request of a form that has file upload and then convert the file in base64 encoded form.

Looked at the examples shown in the play framework site, but it only explains about uploading a file and storing it in some location. But what if I need to convert the uploaded image into a base64 encoded form??

I looked through various resources, could not find what I was looking for. I just have a simple form that uploads image and need convert the upload image to base64 encoding. And yes I am using play framework.

Any help, please.

Update:
What I was actually searching for was:

```
val imageRaw:Option[play.api.mvc.MultipartFormData.FilePart[play.api.libs.Files.TemporaryFile]] = request.body.file("picture").map { picture =>
        picture
      }
```

Now how do I convert the `imageRaw` to base64 encoded string, I don't need to store the image in the disk.

Update2:

What I really had to achieve was load an image using drag and drop functionality and then load the image in a HTML5 canvas, had no problems with other browsers but since IE9 doesn't support FileReader Api, I couldn't retrieve its imageData after its loaded using the DnD functionality.

So, now I am trying to use polyfills to be able to use FileReader API in IE9, does anyone have any idea or samples of how to use them. I have been trying to use [FileReader API](https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader) for now, but can't get to know how to use it.

Comment: Can't you just read the uploaded file and convert it to Base64, e.g. using Apache Commons? There are plenty of questions on SO that cover that.

Comment: Definitely as colleague above says just read uploaded file eg. as input stream or as file and use Apache Commons. I was recently dealing with uploaded files especially with storing them on hard drive and from `MultipartFormData` you can get `FilePart` from that `File` and if you have `File` you can do whatever you want using `Apache Commons`.

Comment: Sorry for the very very late reply, had been busy with this project and deadline.